# Android emulator doesn't start after system update

Tags: android, android-emulator

I recently updated my Lubuntu version 11.4 to 11.10. Before, I had no problems to start the emulator. Now when I try starting an emulator from the AVDM the "Starting Android Emulator" window appears, loads completly and disappears. Nothing more happens. The emulator neither appears in DDMS, so there aren't any log entries I could post. When I enter "adb devices" in the terminal, I get an empty list.
Another weird thing is, that when I try to delete an emulator in the AVDM, before I tried to start it of course,  the error message: "The android Virtual Device ist currently running in an emulator and cannot be deleted" appears. Maybe it has something to do with the starting problem. (I know how to delete an emulator manually, by deleting the ./android/avd/myemulator files.)
Is it perhaps a problem with the graphics? After I updated my System, I had a black screen, so I had to modify the xorg.conf file. I added an extra resolution of 1900x1200.
I already tried to start emulators with different API Levels and different Skin/Resulution properties and different Screen Resulutions.
Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this before.  I would just delete the old emulator you were starting. and re-create a new one (with a different name).

Otherwise, can you give more information: What version of Android are you using for the emulator?  Are you using HAXM?

Bottom line, starting fresh with a brand new AVD\Emulator instance usually fixes these sort of weird issues.

Comment: Sorry, I already deleted all emulators, recreated them. I even downloaded the sdk tools again and replaced the old one. I'm using the SDK Tools 20.0.3, the latest version. I don't use HAXM. When I enter ps aux -L | less in the terminal after starting an emulator, no new process appears. I guess the process:                     root      1050  1111  0.0   65  0.2  27836  1268 ?        Sl   Nov01   0:00 /usr/sbin/console-kit-daemon --no-daemon                     has nothing to do with it, right?

Comment: I am running the emulator now (on my Mac).  When I ps and grep for cosole-kit-daemon, I don't have that process, so I don't think that process has any relevance.  It looks like your emulator isn't starting at all - to confirm your suspicion.   Is there a log file for the emulator that might have a error message?

Comment: thanks for your help so far. Yes, thats what I think too, my emulator doesn't start at all. As I wrote, neither the ddms nor eclipse nor the terminal recognizes an emulator, so there is no logfile I could post. Isnt't there maybe another way to start the emulator but from the Android Virtual Device Manager?

Comment: Yes, you can start the emulator from the command line.  Try: $ emulator -avd myAvdName

Comment: When I enter emulator -avd API16, I get a segmentation faul as an error message. So I tried to enter "emulator -gpu on @API16" in the command line. Than an emulator starts, but the screen of the emulator is first blck and turns then into white and stays white, no matter how long I wait. But at least I can post a logfile now. I posted several errors, which are repeated several times and the output form the terminal, which seems to be repeated in a loo. I think it has something to do with the first error message I hadn't before I think. ![Log.txt][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/tSK6k.jpg